# JavaScript : Print popup taking parent page content in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, printing

I have an issue when try to print a Popup on IE

I use the window.print() function and it's work perfectly on all browsers, but on IE the result has the parent page content.

I try to open the model on a new page, but I get a big problem with the style, and I need to create a new style file for the new page.

Is there any solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refer this example may help you to only print the popup in IE browser.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
@media screen {
  #printSection {
      display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  #printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility:visible;
  }
  #printSection {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }
}



</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>Bootstrap Modal Example</h1>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">
    Large modal
  </button>
</div>
 <div id="printThis">
<div id="MyModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    
    <!-- Modal Content: begins -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      
      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Your Headings</h4>
      </div>
    
      <!-- Modal Body -->  
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="body-message">
          <h4>Any Heading</h4>
          <p>And a paragraph with a full sentence or something else...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <!-- Modal Footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      <button id="btnPrint" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Print</button>
      </div>
    
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Content: ends -->
    
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
    printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
}

function printElement(elem) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
    
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
    
    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }
    
    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

I printed it as a PDF to show the result here.

[image]

Reference:

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/designify-me/pen/gMMepB?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=fa1deec9f3fec3b43aec492d3ab0697a21db315c-1576834494-0-AQOROR4KlUfNdBel2T1ZvWLT-x3krEBqAXDfQOUzpvwibDUfsqW5akYCT9XfraKOnfYgSI0sglSFBAiUyDKlLADsSv3_65WryJY1RwhQM-eEeonF8WD2UQpeDFEwIJ6PQi7ZPBakEM2frpkBm8Te_A1CnPGc9LPGI6uwhnpt-Kjdtau5z6jRGB5Eya9vHNEXB7TuqNQkbivGN1Uu6eK4ozmnYqbOt4tAXU7HV9sjp7NY6EmoEOBDDj1UPI092vHV-zLkZuVt4EevuBhmEd52329jqd_xnpeIfBCSGn-rJ_orYnLwIgCdD_GyCo2b2E5pT1V_QkIA7BmW52BkewbC9prclKN2FoaMY0SlHIP3PkD5)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I fix the issue with just the CSS code on `@media print`